# application stack trace interpretation using mdb

Tags: c, debugging, solaris

Can someone please help me with interpreatation of this stack trace:

```
        Loading modules: [ libumem.so.1 libc.so.1 libuutil.so.1 ld.so.1 ]
        > $c
        libc.so.1`strlen+0xc(80b37ba, fe679d2c, fe679d00, 0)
        libc.so.1`snprintf+0x74(fe67d970, 1388, 80b37b8, efef9f68, 80b379d, fe679e30)
        > 80b37ba::whatis
        80b37ba is unknown
        > fe679d2c::whatis
        fe679d2c is unknown
        > fe679d00::whatis
        fe679d00 is unknown
```

strlen function gets one argument, but in this stack trace I see 3 addresses ? What is the meaning of them ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger doesn't manage to interpret most of it.

The debugger may not know how many parameters a function gets. So it prints more. But you can ignore the extra parameters.

The parts that do make sense show that `snprintf` was called, and then call `strlen`. This is probably due to `%s` in the format string. The `strlen` parameter is similar (not identical, I don't know why), to `snprintf`'s 3rd parameter.
So probably some code does something like `snprintf("%d %s\n", number, string)`.
You can find the actual format string at `fe67d970`, and it will probably let you identify who called it (unless you use the same format string everywhere).